# Formatting code for comments

Tags: support

Currently, when I need to add code formatting to my comments I click the "help" link and copy/paste the "`" character to format the code.

What is the key combination to insert this character?

Comment: What operating system do you use? What keyboard layout? This is really a SuperUser.com-topic though.

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I type the tick and backtick characters on Windows?](http://superuser.com/q/254076)

Comment: On a standard U.S. keyboard, that key is to the left of "1" above the tab key.

Comment: @AlEverett: Wow I am blind. Thanks. Do you want to add that as an answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: I can do that, sure.

Comment: Not arguing, just want to understand. Why is this too localized?

Comment: Hi Shai, I closed this as it seems to be an oversight that isn't likely to repeat (based on your [comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170300/formatting-code-for-comments#comment503792_170300)) Glad you got it sorted :)

Comment: @TimPost: Fair enough. Thanks for responding. Should I delete the question?

Comment: @ShaiCohen: You can't now that there is an answer with upvotes, I'm afraid.

Comment: @ShaiCohen There's no reason to immediately delete it, content here is curated over time. At the time that I closed it, there was no accepted answer, the closure gave a clear indication to others viewing new questions that this particular question did not need any more attention. You didn't do anything wrong :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a standard U.S. keyboard, that key is to the left of <kbd>1</kbd> above the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.